# Where can I ask about programmers' research methods?

Tags: support, site-rec

I asked this question several months ago:

> Title: What is a reasonable way to find canonical books?
>
> I see dozens of questions of the form 'Is there a canonical book on
>   {topic here}?'. My question is different. What are some reasonable
>   ways to go about answering this kind of question for myself?
>
> Currently I look at the most popular books in a category on amazon,
>   but I find this unsatisfying, as the top spots tend to be filled with
>   very introductory or very buzz-wordy books.

There were several thoughtful and thorough answers. Note that the answers were not reading lists but methods and resources for doing research. I'd like to know how I can modify this question such that it wouldn't be frozen and deleted.

This is a similar (but different) question, which seems to have been well received: 
[How Do I Determine the Value of a Technical book?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166314/how-do-i-determine-the-value-of-a-technical-book/166343#166343) I don't believe its title reflect its final question: "Can you provide advice on finding more books along that vein (the Pragmatic Programmer)?"

Comment: FYI, if anyone is wondering, the question being referred to is [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/221451/what-is-a-reasonable-way-to-find-canonical-books).

Comment: Thanks Cupcake. I hadn't found that link yet. The final question was longer than the original, above. I think my attempt to make it less broad made it into a reading-list question, which wasn't actually what I was seeking.

Comment: The only reason I found your question at all was because it was linked to from [the copycat website](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=407329) that you pointed out on MSO. You'll find the link at the bottom in a big red button that says "View full post on Programmers", or something like that. On a side note, those bastards nofollowed that link, which is a big Stack Exchange Creative Commons license no-no `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake: We're getting a bit off-topic here, but where does it stipulate in the CC license that nofollow is forbidden in attributions?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the bottom of the Stack Exchange pages say "user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [**attribution required**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)". That link goes to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), which states that "links must *not* be nofollowed." I guess it's not *strictly* a part of the actual CC license, but don't people reusing CC licensed material have to follow the licencor's attribution terms?

Comment: @Cupcake: No, I don't think so.  The attribution terms are [here](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode#s3a), and it doesn't say anything about licensors spelling out their own attribution terms.  Clearly, copying cc:wiki material to create one's own website and then `nofollowing` the return links is blatantly abusive, but it's an SEO issue, not a licensing one.